# Threadpool program runs much slower on much faster server

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

**upd** I now think that root of my problem not "threading", because I observe slowdown at any point of my program. I think somehow when using 2 processors my program executes slower probably because two processors need to "communicate" between each other. I need to do some tests. I will try to disable one of the processors and see what happens.

====================================

I'm not sure if this is C# question, probably it more about hardware, but I think C# will be most suitable.

I was using cheap DL120 server and I decided to upgrade to much more expensive 2 processors DL360p server. Unexpectedly my C# program works about ~2 times slower on new server which supposed to be several times faster.

I processed [FAST](http://fixprotocol.org/fast) data for about 60 Instruments. I have created separate Task for each Instrument like that:

```
        BlockingCollection<OrderUpdate> updatesQuery;
        if (instrument2OrderUpdates.ContainsKey(instrument))
        {
            updatesQuery = instrument2OrderUpdates[instrument];
        } else
        {
            updatesQuery = new BlockingCollection<OrderUpdate>();
            instrument2OrderUpdates[instrument] = updatesQuery;
            ScheduleFastOrdersProcessing(updatesQuery);
        }
        orderUpdate.Checkpoint("updatesQuery.Add");
        updatesQuery.Add(orderUpdate);
    }

    private void ScheduleFastOrdersProcessing(BlockingCollection<OrderUpdate> updatesQuery)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Instrument instrument = null;
            OrderBook orderBook = null;
            int lastRptSeqNum = -1;
            while (!updatesQuery.IsCompleted)
            {
                OrderUpdate orderUpdate;
                try
                {
                    orderUpdate = updatesQuery.Take();
                } catch(InvalidOperationException e)
                {
                    Log.Push(LogItemType.Error, e.Message);
                    continue;
                }
                orderUpdate.Checkpoint("received from updatesQuery.Take()");
                ......................
                ...................... // long not interesting processing code
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Because I have about 60 task which can be executed in parallel I expect that 2 * E5-2640 (24 virtual threads, 12 real threads) should perform much more faster than 1 * E3-1220 (4 real threads). It seems that using DL360p I found 95 threads in task manager. Using DL120 I have only 55 threads.

But execution time on DL120G7 is 2 (!!) times faster!
E3-1220 has a little bit better clock rate than E5-2640 (3.1 GHz vs 2.5Ghz) however I still expect that my code should work faster on 2 * E5-2640 because it can be paralleled much better and I absolutely do not expect that it work 2 times slower!

[HP DL120G7 E3-1220](http://ark.intel.com/products/52269/)

~50 threads in Task Manager best = 24 average ~ 80 microseconds

```
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 23 updatesQuery.Add = 25 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 67 in orderbook = 80
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 30 updatesQuery.Add = 32 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 64 in orderbook = 73
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 31 updatesQuery.Add = 32 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 195 in orderbook = 204
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 31 updatesQuery.Add = 32 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 74 in orderbook = 86
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 18 updatesQuery.Add = 21 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 65 in orderbook = 78
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 29 updatesQuery.Add = 32 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 76 in orderbook = 88
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 30 updatesQuery.Add = 32 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 80 in orderbook = 92
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 20 updatesQuery.Add = 21 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 65 in orderbook = 78
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 21 updatesQuery.Add = 24 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 68 in orderbook = 81
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 12 updatesQuery.Add = 13 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 58 in orderbook = 72
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 22 updatesQuery.Add = 23 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 51 in orderbook = 59
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 16 updatesQuery.Add = 16 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 20 in orderbook = 24
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 28 updatesQuery.Add = 31 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 82 in orderbook = 94
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 18 updatesQuery.Add = 21 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 65 in orderbook = 77
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 29 updatesQuery.Add = 29 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 259 in orderbook = 264
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 49 updatesQuery.Add = 52 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 99 in orderbook = 113
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 22 updatesQuery.Add = 23 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 50 in orderbook = 60
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 29 updatesQuery.Add = 32 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 76 in orderbook = 88
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 16 updatesQuery.Add = 19 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 63 in orderbook = 75
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 27 updatesQuery.Add = 27 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 226 in orderbook = 231
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 15 updatesQuery.Add = 16 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 35 in orderbook = 42
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 18 updatesQuery.Add = 21 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 66 in orderbook = 78
```

[HP DL360p G8 2 * E5-2640](http://ark.intel.com/ru/products/64591/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2640-%2815M-Cache-2_50-GHz-7_20-GTs-Intel-QPI%29)

~95 threads in Task Manager; best = 40 average ~ 150 microseconds

```
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 62 updatesQuery.Add = 64 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 144 in orderbook = 205
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 27 updatesQuery.Add = 32 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 101 in orderbook = 154
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 45 updatesQuery.Add = 50 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 124 in orderbook = 187
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 46 updatesQuery.Add = 51 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 127 in orderbook = 162
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 63 updatesQuery.Add = 68 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 137 in orderbook = 174
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 53 updatesQuery.Add = 55 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 133 in orderbook = 171
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 44 updatesQuery.Add = 46 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 131 in orderbook = 158
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 37 updatesQuery.Add = 39 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 102 in orderbook = 140
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 45 updatesQuery.Add = 50 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 115 in orderbook = 154
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 50 updatesQuery.Add = 55 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 133 in orderbook = 160
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 26 updatesQuery.Add = 50 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 99 in orderbook = 111
 calling market.UpdateFastOrder = 14 updatesQuery.Add = 30 received from updatesQuery.Take() = 36 in orderbook = 40   <-- best one I can find among thousands
```

Are you able to see why my program runs 2 times slower on several times faster server? Probably I should not create ~60 Task? Probably I should tell .NET not to use 95 threads but to limit it to 50 or even 24? Probably this is 2 processors vs 1 processor configuration issue? Probably just disabling one of the processors on my DL360P Gen8 will speed-up program significantly?

**Added**

- calling market.UpdateFastOrder - orderUpdate object is created
- updatesQuery.Add - orderUpdate is put into BlockingCollection
- received from updatesQuery.Take() - orderUpdate ejected from BlockingCollection
- in orderbook - orderUpdated is parsed and applied to orderBook

Comment: Run a profiler to see where the time is spent. That said, real concurrency requires proper decoupling of things, e.g. very careful use of synchronization. If you're using locks for synchronization this may be the thing that actually slows you down more with additional cores than it speeds you up.

Comment: @Lucero what profilier should I run and how? I don't have VS or anything like that installed on server...

Comment: You don't need VS; there are a bunch of profilers out there, such as the one from [JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/). This is probably the only viable solution to find the performance culprit.

Comment: you can profile on your own machine too - I think it's a fair guess that most machines have multi-cpu nowadays

Comment: @CarstenKönig my own machine doesn't have 2 * E5-2640 and I observe slowness only in this configuration. (moreover my own machine is not connected to stock exchange and can not receive FAST data)

Comment: @javapowered: but it should be possible to find critical locks with a good profiler - if not add some arbitrary delays to *slow* your computation down - should have similar consequences as *fast* data

Comment: I saw similar issues when I went from an old compaq with 4 CPUS and 3gb ram, to a 16 core with 128gb ram.. my speed went to about 6x as slow.. To the point I kept running it on the older server .. My app was to traul through directories on a NAS, so local disk etc wasnt an issue. Does defy a lot of apparent logic, but the bottle necks can be found, I just chose not to waste my time as it was an experiment.

Comment: Install Visual Studio on the server while you debug. Get another sever as standby / for development. High parallel NEEDS proper platform for programming. Visual studio has a GREAT profiler for exactly what you see.

Comment: Could you explain what do your log entries mean? And what exactly do you do in the “not interesting processing code”? Because something in there could be causing the slowdowns, I think.

Comment: @svick I don't think something is there causing slowdowns. Actually I observe slowdown at any point of my program.. So this is probably not about threads. This is probably about "2 processor" vs "1 processor" configuration.

Comment: @javapowered Don't make guesses, use empirical data. Find out what's taking so long and whether threads are waiting for each other (using a profiler). And if you think it's not about threads, then write a test program and find out whether it's actually true.

Comment: they pay you $2000 a day to resolve this and you are asking on the free board.. nice!

Comment: @Bobb what do you mean? what $2000 a day?

Comment: people who work with fast fix are the top paid in the industry. if you are not receiving it you should quit. 99% of fast fix is with sponsored access to exchange. the top dogs only

Comment: @javapowered on topic - you should not use TPL in your situation. TPL is to lower entry point into multi-threading world. this is not the way to build sub-millisecond systems.

Comment: @Bobb what is faster than TPL and why it is faster?

Comment: TPL is a big wrapper to multi-threading. working with TPL on very low-latency app is like using VB6 form designer versus raw XAML. cost of making simple multi-threading is low, cost of making it very sophisticated and manageable is high... this discussin is off topic here. I dont deny you using TPL. Please do by all means.

Comment: @Bobb but can you provide references? Because I remember I was readong that Microsoft recomends TPL because it can better deside how to organize things.

Comment: It looks like you are creating a Task for each instrument, which is fine.  However, it appears that all the order data is coming in serially through one method, and then being dispatched to the appropriate queue (after being created, if necessary).  How much time is being taken to read all of the orders?

Comment: @MonroeThomas what you wrote is correct. but i do not understand the question. it's about ~2000-3000 of orders every second for about ~100 instruments totally

Comment: Can you use ConcurrentBag instead of BlockingCollection? It uses ThreadLocal storage, so threads doesn't interact a lot. And use profiler to check where time goes (synchronization, cache misses etc.)

Answer (score 0):

just because you have a System which can handle much more threads, this does not mean that all of them can be fully processed parallel.

When I upgrade from a Quadcore CPU to a i7(virtual 8 cores), I noticed that a setup using more threads than cores resulted in the threads blocking each other for some time, which lead to an overall slowdown of the System.

The problem was just that my algorythims already were capable of using the full processing time of the core their thread was running on while waiting threads only worked on about 5 to 10%, which lead to the main threads to finish but some singe threads still having to do all their work(taking the same amout of time again).

The threadpool will only continue if all workers have finished, so the total amount of time until finishing will be unuset processor time for the other threads.

maybe you just need to find an optimal number of threads.

Comment: how can I manage number of threads? i just create tasks and .NET decides how many threads to use...

Comment: You would have to create the threadpool manually. If you give me some time I could also give you a code example, but actually I don't have the code of my application here, but here the msdn: [A quick example for a manual ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: @Corsair Or you could [configure the number of threads in the pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads.aspx). But there's usually a better solution, that fixes the underlying problem. And the code in question doesn't actually use the threadpool.

Comment: @svick I'm using `Task` so I allow .NET decide how many threads should be created. .NET should use "optimal" number of threads depending on how many resources are available. So .NET uses internal threadpool. But anyway I now think that this is "2 processors"  configuration problem. I want to disable one of the processors and check what happens.

Comment: @javapowered Using `Task` doesn't automatically mean it uses the `ThreadPool`. It usually does, but you specify you want to create a new thread (outside the pool) for each `Task` if you specify `LongRunning` option. *Which is exactly what you do.*