# how to use power of 2 * Xeon E5?

Tags: c#

I have two servers one running one E3-1220 processor and another running two E5-2640 processors. http://ark.intel.com/compare/52269,64591

The problem is that two processors server which is 5 times more expensive executes my program 2 times slower, see my question on stackoverflow [Threadpool program runs much slower on much faster server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096169/threadpool-program-runs-much-slower-on-much-faster-server))

I wrote this simple program to compare E3-1220 and E5-2640
It doesn't do anything, it's just something I do in real world:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestSpeed
{
    class Program
    {
        private static double a;
        private static double b;
        private static double c = 0.34;
        private static double d = 0.15;
        private static double e = 0.25;
        private static double f = 0.03;
        private static double g = 8;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
            {
                double e = a;
                a = 1;
                double f = b;
                b = 1;
                if (true)
                {
                    double h = 1.83;

                    double j = Math.Ceiling(h/d);
                    if (j <= c)
                    {
                        c = Math.Ceiling(h/d + e);
                    }
                    else if (j > c)
                    {
                        c = Math.Ceiling(h/d - e);
                    }
                    if (c <= -0.5)
                    {
                        a = a - f*c;
                    }

                    double k = Math.Floor(h/d);
                    if (k <= g)
                    {
                        g = Math.Floor(h/d + e);
                    }
                    else if (k > g)
                    {
                        g = Math.Floor(h/d - e);
                    }
                    if (g > 0.5)
                    {
                        b = b + f*g;
                    }
                }

                bool result = (Math.Abs(e - a) > 0) ||
                              (Math.Abs(f - b) > 0);
            }
            long time = sw.ElapsedTicks / (Stopwatch.Frequency / (1000L * 1000L));
            Console.WriteLine(time);

        }
    }
}
```

E5-2640 is new Intel processor and I suppose it should be at least a little bit better then previous E3-1220 which is almost 5 times cheaper.

But the results are: Xeon E5-2640 is 31182 (~31 second), Xeon E3-1220 is 26650 (~26 seconds).
So the ratio is 31182/26650 = 1.17
Clock ratio is 3 / 2.5 = 1.2

So there are absolutely no difference between Xeon E3 and Xeon E5. E3 has 20% higher clock ratio and so works 20 percent faster. What can I do, probably I can use some special Xeon E5 instructions somehow?

And what's very annoying is that in real application Xeon E5 is 2 times(!!) slower than Xeon E3... (refer to my linked question)

So the question is - what can I do to use power of 2 * Xeon E5 configuration? What techniques should I use probably any guidelines how to program on C# to use the power of multiprocessor configurations?

I just disapointed that I spent $10 000 to buy server which executes my program 2 times slower than existent server which I bought for just $1 500

Answer (score 1):

In my little bit of experience the Task Parallel Library has done a great job of creating the right number of threads to maximize your CPU.  Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx

Comment: i'm using `Task` intensively but cheap Xeon E3-1220 is still faster

Answer (score 1):

First of all: this test not decide what server is the best (the $10 000 or the $1 500), because in the price are included several things, like quality of the materials, power supply, HD, etc. etc. etc. Your test can calculate the amount of arithmetic operations (that involves mainly the processor and memory bus).

In my Xeon E5410 @ 2.33GHz - 4GB RAM (Virtual Machine - 4 cores) I get these results:

```
425872098
Time Elapsed: 00:05:56.9214226
```

But the biggest mistake is: The server are using only 25% of the power (1 core).

So I used the [Parallel Task Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608.aspx) and the 4 cores ran out in 100% of the power.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestSpeed
{
    class Program
    {
        private static double a;
        private static double b;
        private static double c = 0.34;
        private static double d = 0.15;
        private static double e = 0.25;
        private static double f = 0.03;
        private static double g = 8;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Parallel.For(0, 1000000000, (p) =>
            {
                double e = a;
                a = 1;
                double f = b;
                b = 1;
                if (true)
                {
                    double h = 1.83;

                    double j = Math.Ceiling(h / d);
                    if (j <= c)
                    {
                        c = Math.Ceiling(h / d + e);
                    }
                    else if (j > c)
                    {
                        c = Math.Ceiling(h / d - e);
                    }
                    if (c <= -0.5)
                    {
                        a = a - f * c;
                    }

                    double k = Math.Floor(h / d);
                    if (k <= g)
                    {
                        g = Math.Floor(h / d + e);
                    }
                    else if (k > g)
                    {
                        g = Math.Floor(h / d - e);
                    }
                    if (g > 0.5)
                    {
                        b = b + f * g;
                    }
                }

                bool result = (Math.Abs(e - a) > 0) ||
                              (Math.Abs(f - b) > 0);
            });
            sw.Stop();
            long time = sw.ElapsedTicks / (Stopwatch.Frequency / (1000L * 1000L));
            Console.WriteLine(time);
            Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.ToString());
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
359930438
Time Elapsed: 00:05:01.6560249
```

Almost one minute, okay, this means that no matter how many threads you can run simultaneously, the difference is small. Maybe the cache (L1 or L2) are insufficient to hold some variables and force more RAM roundtrips, or maybe the answer is not in your processor, but in your **code**.

Comment: @javapowered Yes, first check that your code is not the problem, run with a profiler on the target system.

Comment: Not being a c#er, but could the problem not be that each task is so small that most of the work is spent in overhead of scheduling the tasks? What happens if you partition the work differently, such as in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560853.aspx ?